# How to host more then one static websites, S3 buckets under one aws domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have one registered domain in `AWS`, for example `www.example.com`
I am wondering if it is possible to connect more then one `S3 buckets` to it through `Route 53`.

My domain `www.example.com` is created as a `CNAME` record with the value `example.com` in `Route53`.
And I already have a Load Balancer with the name `example.com` connected to it, as an `A IPv-4 address`, so I can`t create another record with the same name.

I was wondering if adding a prefix, e.g `exercise.`, so `www.exercise.example.com` would work and naming the `S3 bucket` the same name?

And doing so for each new bucket, of course with a different prefix/name each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put AWS cloudfront in front of your website, you will have much more flexibility - including using content from multiple buckets/origins and using subdomains as you suggested.

With cloudfront there is no requirement that the s3 bucket name match the domain, so it gives you more flexibility.

Comment: do i need a cloudfront per each S3 bucket website ?